# JSON-type Error response handler for Spring controller

Tags: java, json, spring

I have this exception handler which works just fine:

```
@ExceptionHandler(DataNotExistException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason = "Data not exist")
public void handleDataNotExistException() {

}
```

I need to put this exception handler to the exception will not be shown in the browser. Although it works, it shows the "generic" Jetty Browser error codes. I need to have a JSON-type response type.

I tried returning a Class-type error but the exception shows in the browser. I am thinking of using a Map.

Comment: I tried returning a Map but it did not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your request contains the header **Accept=application/json** then annotate your method with `@ResponseBody` and return the object that will be transformed to json. Remove the reason from `@ResponseStatus`.